# Recommendation for tools to migrate from TFS to SVN

Tags: svn, tfs

Can you recommend any tool to migrate sources (with history) from TFS to SVN?

Answer (score 22):

Have you looked at [tfs2svn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tfs2svn/)?

> tfs2svn is a Windows application that
>   converts a Team Foundation Server
>   (TFS) repository into a Subversion
>   (SVN) repository, preserving the
>   history, branches, and commit
>   information.

Comment: Using tfs2svn v1, I always get the first changeset migrated into svn but then the client just hangs and does not import anymore changesets from TFS. Anyone else experienced this with tfs2svn?

Comment: I was also unable to use it.  It would error out on different changesets on different files with different errors.  Never managed to get all the way through.

Comment: I successfully used tfs2svn to migrate a repository with over five years of history and nearly 21,000 changesets. I wrote about the challenges I encountered and how I overcame them at http://esmithy.net/2011/02/01/migrating-from-tfs-to-svn/.

Answer (score 1):

We are migrating TFS 2010 collections into svn. To make it work for us I needed to download and modify the source of TFS2SVN so that it understood the collections we had made.

At the moment I just hard coded the values because we are only going to use this twice. We modified tfs2svn\trunk\Colyar.SourceControl.Tfs2Svn\Tfs2SvnConverter.cs as follows

```
public Tfs2SvnConverter(string tfsPath, string svnPath, bool createSvnFileRepository, int fromChangeset, string workingCopyPath, string svnBinFolder, bool doInitialCheckout, string tfsUsername, string tfsPassword, string tfsDomain)
    {
        ParsePaths(tfsPath, svnPath);
        this._tfsServer = "http://<tfs domain>:8080/tfs/<team project collection name>";
        this._tfsRepository = "<remote source location>"; // "$/<team project name>/..."
        //this._tfsExporter = new TfsExporter(this._tfsServer, this._tfsRepository, workingCopyPath, fromChangeset, tfsUsername, tfsPassword, tfsDomain);
        TfsClient.Provider.Connect(this._tfsServer, this._tfsRepository, workingCopyPath, fromChangeset, tfsUsername, tfsPassword, tfsDomain);

        this._svnImporter = new SvnImporter(this._svnRepository, workingCopyPath, svnBinFolder);
        _createSvnFileRepository = createSvnFileRepository;
        _doInitialCheckout = doInitialCheckout;
        _workingCopyPath = workingCopyPath;

        HookupTfsExporterEventHandlers();
    }
```

Comment: Did your solution work once you made the code change? According to http://sourceforge.net/projects/tfs2svn/forums/forum/772710/topic/4548185 it looks like the code change didnt work for someone.

Comment: Sorry, actually just saw your comment (years later). If I recall we gave up in the end, grabbed latest from TFS, and imported that into SVN.