# Strategies for migrating TFS2005 to Subversion

Tags: svn, tfs, migration

We are on TFS2005 and we are definitely not using all of it's capabilities. All we use it for right now is it's source code repository. For CI we are using CruiseControl as TFS2005 will not build .NET3.5 applications. Moving to TFS2010 is one of our considerations but we are also thinking of just moving to Subversion.

Anyone done a TFS to Subversion migration? Any tips to share? I would really like to move the history of files too but i tried [using the tfs2svn tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371203/tfs-to-svn) without success. Anyone tried anything else?

Comment: Can't wait to see the answers you get!

Comment: I can't wait to see if LordHits wants to modify Vss2SVN to create the first TFS2SVN tool.

Comment: Well, me thinks it would make more sense to modify the original tfs2svn located here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tfs2svn/ ? I'm going to relook at that code some more.

Comment: absolutely. May I ask you write down your experiences with it and get it all posted to the svn mailing list at the very least. Good luck.

Comment: We landed up just sticking with TFS and upgraded to TFS2008. Fastest thing we could think of for now and unfortunately, I don't have the time to work on tfs2svn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understand the [Team Foundation API](http://notsosmartbuilder.blogspot.com/2006/07/tfs-api.html), you can grab the [vss2svn](http://vss2svn.codeplex.com/) project from codeplex, and replace the VSS calls with TFS ones. It basically grabs a version 1 by 1 and adds them to SVN, thus keeping full history. As the app is a .NET one, the replacement calls should be very straightforward.

Its just a pity you can't get a refund for TFS :)