# Migrations of Source code with history from TFS to SVN using TFS2SVN, client hangs

Tags: svn, tfs, visualsvn

I am trying to convert all the source code along with history from TFS collection to SVN repository. I am using the source code of TFS2SVN (r107).

While conversion I am selecting option of OpenTF 0.5.2 alpha as TFS client library (in TFS2SVN). I am choosing to uncheck option, "Do initial checkout". When I run the code it hangs at "RunSvnCommand" function at line "p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()" (various other ways are attempted to avoid ReadToEnd problem, but did not work. Not posting all those attempts, as not recorded the different version of code changes & observations)

**Please let me know the cause & workaround of the issue.**
In addition to this, I am wondering from where to provide the SVN authentications to SVN users, while using TFS2SVN, (or it is not needed here).

Before posting the question

1. I have gone through `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371203/tfs-to-svn` ([TFS to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371203/tfs-to-svn));
2. Merged the changes suggested by Eric Smith (esmithy.net/2011/02/01/migrating-from-tfs-to-svn; IncludeChange function etc.);
3. In config file I have modified TFS user & SVN user mapping entries.